# python subprocess con ffmpeg se para al lanzar una salida con ffmpeg

Tags: python

Estoy intentando capturar la salida con ffmpeg y me he fijado que este binario lanza las salidas por el `stderr` pero me di cuenta que cuando el archivo ya existe me lo lanza por stdout pero aquí tengo un problema y es que el script se me queda bloqueado, mi proposito es capturar las salidas sin esperar a que el proceso termine tanto el `stdout` como el `stdin` pero no logro hacerlo.

Si el archivo no existe todo funciona muy bien pero si exsite entonces me encuentro aqui con el problema.

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
from time import sleep
import subprocess

p = Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','rufian.mp4','-f','mp3','rufiannn.mp3'],stdin=PIPE,\
            stdout=PIPE,\
            stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)

while p.poll() == None:
    err = p.stderr.readline()
    print(err)
```

el problema es que una vez existe el archivo el script se detiene porque la consola dice si quiere sobreescribirlo y no puedo capturar esto de ninguna manera ni siquiera con `stdout.readline()` , con communicate no me sirve porque siempre espera a que el proceso termine.

¿hay alguna solución para esto? por ahora lo único que encuentro es tener que programar yo código para comprobar si existe.

Comment: ¿Has probado con el parámetro `-y` de ffmpeg? La otra posibilidad es verificar la existencia del archivo previamente y borrarlo en caso que exista.

Comment: Tal y como comenta Patricio `-y` debe forzar la sobreescritura sin preguntar: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options. La verdad es que la particular forma de mostrar las salidas de ffmpeg es un dolor de cabeza a la hora de capturarlas (una gran parte por stderr como dices) y parsearlas de forma adecuada.

Comment: La opción -y ya la tenia en cuenta pero lo que quiero es hacer correctamente y como decís es un dolor de cabeza y no entiendo nada la forma de salida de ffmpeg por que he puesto stderr=subprocess.STDOUT para que se lance como si fuera una salida normal y capturarlo con out = p.stdout.readline() pero sigue igual todo funciona correctamente pero cuando detecta que existe el archivo se queda bloqueado y es imposible capturar nada lo unico que me queda es detectar si existe el archivo yo mismo con os.path en el caso de que no exista ninguna solucion

Comment: @user2030424 he hecho algunos avances en mi lucha con ffmpeg y su funcionamiento con subprocess (lucha que viene de antes de esta pregunta de hecho). Mira la respuesta por si te sirve de algo, o al menos sacas algo en claro. Como dije ffmpeg tiene sus peculiaridades. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo algunas pruebas he observado que por alguna razón (que por ahora no alcanzo a dilucidar) con `readline` no imprime toda la salida correctamente, queda cortada.

Pues bién, usando `read` si que se puede conseguir obtener toda la salida (lo que en ffmpeg puede ser tanto por ***stdout*** como por ***stderr*** (aunque no sea una excepción, algún día lo entenderé...) sin problemas:

```
import subprocess
import sys



p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','file.mp4','-f','mp3','file1.mp3'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     universal_newlines=True,
                     )

while p.poll() == None:
    out = p.stdout.read(1)
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

`sys.stdout.write(out)` es más rápido que `print(out, end='')` aunque se podría usar `print`.

Al final he conseguido leer toda la salida e incluso poder usar la ***stdin*** ingresando `y` o `N` cuando se pregunta por sobreescribir. El código es una adaptación a las peculiaridades de ffmpeg y añadiendo la posibilidad de usar ***stdin***  de la magnífica respuesta de J.F. Sebatian sobre la lectura no bloqueante en subprocess.PIPE`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/7131499

Mi código no está muy pulido pero a modo de ejemplo funciona como debe:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from threading  import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    while p.poll() == None:
        out = p.stdout.read(1)   
        if out != '':
            queue.put(str(out))


p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','file.mp4','-f','mp3','file1.mp3'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     universal_newlines=True,
                     bufsize=1,
                     close_fds=ON_POSIX
                    )

q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

string = ''
while p.poll() == None:
    try:
        c = q.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        if 'Overwrite ? [y/N]' in string:
            i = input()
            p.stdin.write(i)
            p.stdin.close()
            string = ''
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        string += c
```

**Ejemplo de ejecución en el mismo IDLE:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aviso: el código está probado en Python 3.6 bajo Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todas las respuestas, me ha servido para solucionar el problema, al final dejé el código de la siguiente manera

```
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT
import time


p = Popen('ffmpeg -i rufian.mp4 -f mp3 out.mp3',stdin=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)

tmp = ''
while p.poll() == None:
    out = p.stdout.read(1)
    tmp += out
    if '\n' in out:
        print(tmp)
        tmp = ''
    elif 'Overwrite ? [y/N]' in tmp:
        print(tmp)
        tmp = ''
        p.stdin.write('Y\n')
```